# Can't file 1098-T electronically on Turbotax or Credit Karma

Tags: taxes, income-tax, student-loan, income-tax-refund

Historically, I've been able to claim the American Opportunity Credit that would give a surplus refund of $1000 to help with school while being a full time student and not working

Comment: Are you getting an error when trying to add the 1098-T, or is it that entering it doesn't result in the credit you expected?

Comment: I think both is happening to be honest

Comment: Probably need to contact their support directly to get assistance, but the AOC has limited availability, perhaps you no longer qualify.

Comment: Could it be possible that credit karma is waiting until January 27th to send tax information to the irs?